# Finding common elements based on a condition in django

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I have three models connected through an m2m relationship. Stop represents a bus stop, Route represents a bus route, and RouteStation is an intermediary model connecting Stop and Route to one another, with information about where that stop is on the route (RouteStation.order).

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, default="None")
    stop_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)


class Route(models.Model):
    route_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    journey_pattern = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stops = models.ManyToManyField(Stop, through="RouteStation")


class RouteStation(models.Model):
    stop = models.ForeignKey(Stop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Given two stops, I need to return a queryset containing all routes common to both stops, where the value of RouteStation.order is higher for the second stop than the first. This condition ensures that the second stop is accessible via the first stop on that route.

I can find the common stops using the following:

```
stop1 = Stop.objects.get(stop_id=origin)
stop2 = Stop.objects.get(stop_id=destination)

routes1 = stop1.route_set.all()
routes2 = stop2.route_set.all()
common = routes1 & routes2
```

However I'm having trouble filtering this based on RouteStation.order values. Does anyone know the best way of going about this?

Comment: ?? Do you need the stops field in Route then. The many to many is implemented by the RouteStation model anyway

Comment: Is that a professional Site? Like are you hired to make a real Site for some Public transport Servies or are you "messing around"? Either way I would highly recommend to look into "Dijkstra's Algorithm" and spend a lot of time thinking and understanding the topic. When this needs to be properly working its not done with some QueryFiltering, you need to build a massive Algorithm. When you do this for yourself enjoy and post the results I want to see it :D. If you do this commercial I would recommend to buy an exciting project and implement it.

Comment: @hansTheFranz This is for a university project. We're building a public transport application, and using some simple machine learning on historical transport data to improve upon schedule predictions. I can send you the rest of my code if you're interested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) in this case, as using Django orm is more complicated than necessary.

```
sql = '''
SELECT * FROM yourapp_routestation r1, yourapp_routestation r2
WHERE r1.stop_id = {s1} AND 
  r2.stop_id = {s2} AND
  r1.route_id = r2.route_id AND
  r1.order < r2.order
'''

rs_query = RouteStation.objects.raw(sql.format(s1=stop1.stop_id, s2=stop2.stop_id))
for rs in rs_query:
    print(rs.route_id)
```

Note:

Change `yourapp_routestation` to the actual table name.

`rs_query` is `RouteStation` objects, so you'll get `Route` object with `rs.route`.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I didn't realise you could make queries using raw SQL in Django. However, because I'm referring to Stop and Route objects directly in my RouteStation model, I'm not sure using the route_id is accessing the models correctly. How do you reference other object like that using SQL?

Comment: apologies, I edited my comment above. If it would be more appropriate to ask this second question in a separate thread I'll mark the question answered and make another thread. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @DanielJ See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#database-representation). Briefly, for a `ForeignKey` field, django appends `_id` automatically to the database column name. So `stop` field in `RouteStation` model is represented as `stop_id` column in your database's `yourapp_routestation` table. Check your actual database table to see it in action. :)

Comment: thank you! I was confused as I'm using stop_id and route_id explicitly in my Stop and Route models. I see now that these are different than the stop_id and route_id fields that Django generates itself. Thanks again.